# How to fill countries in a world map using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, colors, fill, country

My client has customers in 100 countries in which a customer can have access to more than a country. So, to show visual appearance to the customer, our client want to show world map and fill each country with a different color where the customer has access to.

Is there anyway to do this in ASP.NET?

If not ASP.NET, Is their any third party which does this stuff.

Could you please let me know what is the best way of doing this?

Thanks a lot,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into this sample: [Sales Dashboard Sample Application](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/salesdashboard/default.aspx). Click on "Country" tab for more info.